# How to Connect PC to ubuntu Beagle board

Tags: ubuntu, linux-device-driver, beagleboard

I have PC connected to beagle board through SERIAL PORT. Ubuntu is running on both PC and beagle board.  I have sensor attached to beagle board . These sensor data is needed by PC from beagle board through serial port.
How to transmit the sensor data to PC from beagle board(running Ubuntu) using serial port ?
Do i need to communicate between two OS ?

Answer (score 1):

In beagleboard.
echo sensor_data > /dev/< serial_device >
eg: echo $DATA > /dev/ttyS0

In Ubuntu pc:
cat  /dev/< serial_device >